# Find out if id is already in a subdocuments array mongoose/mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a user document like this

```
{
    "_id": "userid",
    "posts": [
        {
            "_id": {
                "$oid": "5ad68c4febe84802fcd9feb0"
            },
            "likes": [
                {
                    "_id": {
                        "$oid": "5ad626d578c7b21c0806042e"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to get the document by post id and find out if a user id is already inside the likes array of the same post

How can i do this in mongoose ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is what you posted a plain Javascript object, or something relating to mongoose?

Comment: Thats my mongodb document

Comment: Posts is static or dinamik.This mean posts[0],posts[1].... or only posts.

Comment: Posts is an array of multiple documents ive managed to do it like this but it dosent seem a good way to do it User.find(
        {
            "posts._id": req.params.id,
        },
        "posts.$",
        (err, doc) => {
            if (doc[0].posts[0].likes.some(like => like._id == req.user.id)) {
                console.log('this user already likes this post')
            }
        }
    )

Comment: @NeilLunn i dont have a problem to retrieve the document im just looking for a way to know if it exists in the likes array from the query, i dont want to loop over it on the server

Comment: *"I want to get the document by post id and find out if a user id is already inside the likes array of the same post"* - This is the question which is already comprehensively answered. That's what you asked, and you've been pointed at the solution. Another variant was on the link that closed your previous question as well. Read and learn. It's what you want.